Showing the product in category and search with Magento 2 Observer
I have defined an attribute in Magento 2. When I say Dont Show in Category in this attribute, I do not want the product to be shown in Category and Search. But I don't want to completely remove the product's URL, this is important for me in terms of SEO. Can you help me?
I made the visible property and it did not show the product in the category or search, but when I entered the URL, it gave a 404 error.

Hi Ramazan, Did you check my solution. If it worked for you, please accept the solution and up vote, so that others can know that solution helped.

thank you for replying.I edited the code but it didn't work.I am writing you my full code. Thank you very much in advance.

registration.php

<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Vendor_Module',
 __DIR__


di.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> 
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
    <plugin name="vendor_plugin_model_layer" type="OutOfStock\Observer\Layer" sortOrder="0" />
</type>
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
    <plugin name="vendor_plugin_model_toolbar" type="OutOfStock\Observer\Toolbar" />
</type>


module.xml

 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_Module">
    <sequence>
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </sequence>
</module>


Layer.php

<?php
namespace OutOfStock\Observer;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer as CatalogLayer;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection as ProductCollection;
class Layer
  {
public function aroundgetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, \Closure $proceed)
 {
$collection = $proceed();
 $collection
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('dont_show_outofstock', array('neq' => 222));
    return $collection;
    }
  }


Toolbar.php

<?php

namespace OutOfStock\Observer;

 use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection as 
  ProductCollection;

class Toolbar
 {
  public function aroundgetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer 
  $subject, \Closure $proceed)
 {
    $collection = $proceed();
    $collection
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('dont_show_outofstock', array('neq' => 222));
    return $collection;
}
 }


Attribute;





You need to change Vendor_Module to OutOfStock_Observer in app/code/OutOfStock/Observer/registration.php and app/code/OutOfStock/Observer/etc/module.xml files.

All products are gone from my category page :(

Why are you taking Product Input Type for Store Owner as dropdown. You can simply take it as Yes/No type.

We can't find products matching the selection. I did Text Swatch but it still gives this error

If you have only 2 choices, Show and Not Show, why are you taking swatch or dropdown fields?

I posted a screenshot of the area I created as the picture below in the attribute Properties heading. Could you please write me about what to change?

I am assuming that you want to hide products from category and search pages based on attribute = 'name' and the condition is:

Hide product if name = 'xyz'

Let's start our solution.

File: app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);


File: app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module">
        <sequence>
            <sequence>
                <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            </sequence>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>


File: app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
        <plugin name="vendor_plugin_model_layer" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Layer" sortOrder="0" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="vendor_plugin_model_toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Toolbar" />
    </type>
</config>


File: app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Model/Layer.php

<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer as CatalogLayer;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection as ProductCollection;

class Layer
{
    public function aroundgetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        $collection = $proceed();
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('neq' => 'xyz'));
        return $collection;
    }
}


File: app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Model/Toolbar.php

<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection as ProductCollection;

class Toolbar
{
    public function aroundgetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        $collection = $proceed();
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('neq' => 'xyz'));
        return $collection;
    }
}

Let me know if it helped.

I sent you my codes and screenshot, can you help me?
